# How to initiate designMode of iframe?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, designmode

I'm trying to implement a simple iframe designmode I initiated in javascript into React. My pure js code:

```
<body>
<div id="textEditor">
    <button id="action" title="Bold"><b>Click me</b></button>
    <div id="richTextArea"></div>
        <iframe id="theWYSIWYG" name="theWYSIWYG" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var editor = theWYSIWYG.document;
        editor.designMode = 'on';
</script>
```

This is working of course. But trying in React:

```
class ExamCreate extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.examBody = null
}
state = {
    modalStage: 0,
    newExamName: '',
    newExamDescription: '',
    newExamTime: '',
}
componentDidUpdate = () => {
        var a = this.examBody.document;
        a.designMode = 'on';
}
```

and jsx:

```
<iframe ref={examBody => this.examBody = examBody} 
        id="examBody" name="examBody" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

But I cannot access the ref's document at all. How can I setup the designmode of the iframe ref?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to React and this is confusing to me why don't you wrtie this.state inside of a constructor?

Comment: Hey mate today it's not a problem to define the state outside of the constructor and this is not related to the issue I asked about. Thanks anyhow(:

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by adding the contentWindow property like so:

```
let editor = this.examBody.contentWindow.document;
editor.designMode = 'on'
```

I don't know why different in Reacat and why you cannot reach the document directly, hope it can help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved within body tag outside of React:

```
  <body onLoad='enableEditor()'>
```

and before body closing tag i have a script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

      function enableEditor () {
          todoEditor.document.designMode = 'On'
          todoEditor.focus();
    }

</script>
```

todoEditor is a name of my (iframe name='todoEditor')

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    theWYSIWYG.document.designMode = 'on';
  }, []);
```

```html
<div id="textEditor">
    <button id="action" title="Bold"><b>Click me</b></button>
    <div id="richTextArea"></div>
        <iframe id="theWYSIWYG" name="theWYSIWYG" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).